# Can I restore applications settings from a back up of Ubuntu on a fresh install Lubuntu? (same machine)

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, backup

And in general, I'm wondering if this is possible as I switch between Ubuntu derivatives? (or even Linux distro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit generic, so the answer is a bit generic, too: yes, probably.

Most applications save their settings either

- in a hidden subdirectory of your home directory named after the application, e.g. `~/.thunderbird`,
- in a directory in `~/.config/`, e.g. `~/.config/evolution`, or
- in a hidden file in your home directory, again named after the application, with an append `rc`, e.g. `~/.vimrc`

If you locate the appropriate directory or file and copy it to your new home, the application will (usually) use those restored settings.

**Update**: Changing the hardware doesn't matter as long as the configuration is not specific to that hardware – most configs are not, though.

A different user name might cause problems if the config uses full paths – like `/home/olduser/.something` – instead of paths relative to the current user's home.

Also, on a new installation, the user id might differ, so make sure the files belong to your new user.

In a nutshell, changing the hardware and/or the user id might introduce some small problems, but nothing that can't rather easily be dealt with.

Comment: That's the generic answer I need. I'm having some problems starting up Firefox, so I just want to make sure that copying `.mozzila` is indeed a legit way to transfer settings. Now I can focus on troubleshooting other parts.

Comment: could you edit your answer to add details about cases of 1) same hardware, different account info, 2) different hardware?

Answer (score 1):

To add to the drc's (correct) answer, you can even switch from boot to boot if you have the root partition and the `/home` partition on different places. (See for example my answer here][1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312919/how-to-change-user-gid-and-uid-in-ubuntu-13-04)).

**Warning**: this is advanced user material. Don't do it if you are not confident. Have a backup of your data every time.

I mean, for example: you can have a `/` for Ubuntu on /dev/sda5, a `/` for Fedora on /dev/sda6, and a common `/home` for both on `/dev/sda6`. Then you can choose where to boot each time.

It's tricky but (at least used to) work. I had it when switched from Mandriva to Ubuntu ages ago. The main pitfalls/warnings are:

- if you are using the same user name, you must be sure that [UID and GID are the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312919/how-to-change-user-gid-and-uid-in-ubuntu-13-04) for the two systems;
- sometime configuration files for programs are not forward/backward compatible, which can create problems switching.

But it's basically a lot of fun. You can have even (**more advanced matter**)

- different user names for every system with the same UID (each system has a completely different configuration but you can access your files)
- you can even play with [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) and having the two system available together without virtual machines... (I tried just the [command line  part](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1156240). Graphic console is probably impossible to have without some kind of real virtualization.).