# Lastlog grows to 4.2G after SSH logout

Tags: ssh, files, log

Running a VPS with Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. Noticed a spike in disk usage.
Turns out the culprit is lastlog. Overwrote it with `>/var/log/lastlog`.

After logging out of the session and logging back in, lastlog increases in size again:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 4.2G May  5 06:32 /var/log/lastlog
```

Is this something known? How can I stop lastlog from using up so much space?

Thank you!

Comment: What is printed? It sounds like you have an error that is producing a lot of output. Have you actually _checked_ the logs?

Comment: I can't really open a 4GB log on a VPS.

Comment: Try `tail /var/log/lastlog`. That'll show the last 10 lines of the log. If 10 lines isn't enough, try `tail -n NUM /var/log/lastlog`, where NUM is the number of lines from the bottom you want to show.

Comment: Added both to OP.
Tried tail - it hangs with no output.

Comment: Rsyslog added to OP.

Comment: `lastlog` not `syslog` sorry :\. You can remove the output of `ls -l /etc/logrotate.d`, `logrotate.conf` and `rsyslog`

Comment: Here are some links to the bug reports in Redhat / fedora and ubuntu. Hopefully, more people will call attention to this issue and it will get some attention.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1707645
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=951564

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/var/log/lastlog` is a *sparse* file meaning its real size is not reported by `ls -l` but by `ls -s`. This means that your lastlog might not be as huge as you think:

Try:

```
ls -s /var/log/lastlog
```

to get a report of its size in blocks.

The sudden growth of **/var/log/lastlog** means a high *UID* user as logged out. Look at lastlog [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/lastlog.8.html)

Edit - **To fix it**:

You can found out the last logged out user by using `lastlog` command.

And  after making sure the user is not logged in with `w` command, change its *UID*. See how in "[How to change user gid and uid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312919/how-to-change-user-gid-and-uid-in-ubuntu-13-04)"

Then clear `/var/log/lastlog` like you already did with

```
> /var/log/lastlog
```

*Note*: Using an uid of 6565666, I only got 1.8G for `/var/log/lastlog`. So your user must have an uid higher than 26262664 ???

Comment: I'ts a good answer +1

Comment: I understood it is a sparse file, but the VPS dashboard actually counts it's size in the space used.  lastlog is indeed just 4 blocks. Is there something that I can do about it?

Comment: Change the high UID of user in /etc/passwd to a smaller one ? Find that user in lastlog output (the command not the file /var/log/lastlog). Mark above solution as accepted if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the accepted answer, this is a sparse file which is not really as big as it seems.

However, this can be a problem with backups where the backup file actually will be that big. So for others landing here as I did because the backups are getting too large:

If doing backups of `/var/log`, do them with `rsync` and use its `--sparse` (or `-S`) option.

From `man rsync` :

> -S, --sparse
>
> Try to handle sparse files efficiently so they take up less space on the destination.
>
> If combined with --inplace the file created might not end up with sparse blocks with some combinations of kernel version and/or filesystem type. If --whole-file is in effect (e.g. for a local copy) then it will always work because rsync truncates the file prior to writing out the updated version.
>
> Note that versions of rsync older than 3.1.3 will reject the combination of --sparse and --inplace.